# Swift unit testing and "build for testing" errors

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing

I have a project that build fine until I try to unit test. When I "build for testing" I get several errors. For example these few lines of Swift

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var panAndZoomView: SegmentationPanAndZoomView!
@IBOutlet weak var toolbarView: SegmentationToolbarView!
```

gives two build errors:

> Use of undeclared type 'SegmentationPanAndZoomView'
>
> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<<error type>>'

[image: xcode screenshot]

I have included

```swift
@testable import Thinga_Me
```

to pull in the Product Module Name (as suggested in Kostapappas Lampros's comment on [Swift 2 + Xcode 7: Unit Testing Access Made Easy](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/)), and I have the Testing Target Host Application set with its 'Allow testing Host Application APIs' checked. I have also read through the relevant chapters of the Apple documentation [Testing with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/).

What am I missing to get this app to 'build for testing' given that 'build for running' has no issues?

Comment: could you please show your `SegmentationPanAndZoomView` file and your  `SegmentationToolbarView` file

Comment: They are big - which bits do you need? I don't think they are 'wrong' since the app builds and runs without issue (it's just for testing that the build fails)

Comment: I've left it undeclared, so I think they default to 'internal'

Comment: Are they declared in your Compile Sources under Targets > Build Phases  for your test module?

Comment: Select the file containing the SegmentationPanAndZoomView, open Attributes inspector, and make sure that the box is checked to include it in your test target.

Comment: Thanks - I think you are both onto it. Adding the two to the test modules (through the Build Phases or the Attributes Inspector) seems to remove that error. Feel free to write up as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Sadly I'm getting a similar error but this time from a .h and .mm file. I guess it's harder to build Objective C++ bridging files in Swift unit tests, but that may need a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The issue had to do with having an incorrect class name under "Custom Class" of "Identity Inspector".

[image: Incorrect Class Name]

In my case, I had missed 3 letter class prefix. Hope this helps.